# Disabling Mic before exporting from DAW

Tags: recording

Sorry if this not the right place to ask this question..but i was just wondering how necessary is it to disable the microphone before exporting recorded audio from DAW to wav,mp3,midi,

Answer (score 2):

It’s not at all necessary. Usually you want to take tracks out of record mode before mixing since any microphones connected to tracks that are still record armed might feedback if and when you turn up the volume on the monitors.